# Bad practice to expose private/protected methods during runtime

Tags: php, reflection, callable

Okay I don't know if it's bad design but I feel a bit bad about doing the following:

```
abstract class A
{
    abstract public function getCallable(); 
}

class B extends A
{
    public function getCallable()
    {
        return array($this, 'doSomething');
    }

    protected function doSomething($param1, $param2, $param3)
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

The reason why `B::doSomething` is protected is that I don't like to expose this method because it should only be called from somewhere else in the code where I do a `call_user_func()` for the return value of `B::getCallable`.

You should be free to organize yourself in the subclasses of `A`. Without exposing anything to the outside. So the "API" won't change to the view outside of the subclasses of `A`.

So you should not be able to do something like:

```
$b = new B();
$b->doSomething($param1, $param2, $param3);
```

the only way to get `B::doSomething` executed should be over:

```
$b = new B();
call_user_func($b->getCallable());
```

So I'm thinking about how I could achieve that. One way I could think of is create a `ReflectionMethod` object from `B::getCallable()`'s return value and set it to accessable if the method is not public.

I don't like this solution it would work fine but is not that elegant:

```
class B extends A
{
    public function getCallable()
    {
        return function($param1, $param2, $param3)
        {
            $this->doSomething($param1, $param2, $param3);
        };
    }

    protected function doSomething($param1, $param2, $param3)
    {
        // Do stuff here
    }
}
```

Any good suggestions or other ideas how to work around this?

Comment: Why is this method protected in the first place? Seems like you just want to call it, so set it to public.

Comment: As I mentioned above: "You should be free to organize yourself in the subclasses of `A`. Without exposing anything to the outside. So the class "API" won't change to the view outside of the subclasses of `A`." I also show a "workaround" for this "issue" at the end of my question but I like to solve this mor elegant.

Comment: I think my previous comment came across wrong.  

What i'm saying is this.  When we, or any programmer, specify a function as private / protected; there is usually a reason.  Before you can know if it is bad practice to expose that protected method in the way you are.. you need to identify if the exposure introduces some sort of unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more clear explanation of what i'm trying to articulate.  In the below example you see that I come to realize there is no danger in exposing the doSomething function publicly, so I change it's scope instead of creating a clever intermediary function.

```
class One {
    protected function doSomething( )
    {
        return 'hi';
    }
}


class Two extends One {
    public function doSomething( )
    {
        return parent::doSomething();
    }
}


$Class = new Two();
echo $Class->doSomething();
```

Less is more, so KISS your code ;)

Comment: Beyond this, you're only option would be to hook into whatever Open/Close architecture is present.  If there isn't any, then you can do what you did, or what I suggested.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Well as I mentioned in my question "You should not be able to call the `B::doSomething` method any other way then by provoking the callable returned by the `B::getCallable` method". What I like to achieve by this is a "clean" class API without declaring methods as `public` which only should be used internally by the class which handles the `A` instances. So I can't get it how your could addresses my question..

Comment: Yeah, I just don't see the difference. The function is exposed in either case. Obviously I don't have your answer though. Good luck brothuh! :)

Comment: Yeah that's true but I like to expose it at runtime and through a way where I don't have to make the method public in the class definition itself.